# An action method is created but it still gives the "Http 404 error of missing url"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a form and a button SAVE. I have also created an action method CREATE which will be called when we click SAVE button. I want to see model binding now but when I fill in the form and click save button it shows following error message.[it shows the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd9Sz.png)
See attached code please

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer"))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Customer.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Customer.Name, new { @class="form-control"})
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Customer.BirthDate)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Customer.BirthDate, new { @class="form-control"})
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter) Subscribed to Newsletter?
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
                   @*List of items*@
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Customer.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes,"Id","Name"),"Select",new { @class="form-control"})
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Below is the Create action method from controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You should specify method post in the ...BeginForm, by default the method is get and you need post in this case

Comment: Add FormMethod.Post in your using statement like     @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: Specifying FormMethod.Post did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add an attribute route

```
[Route("~/customer/create")]
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
```

and add a model to the top of the view

```
@model Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customer", FormMethod.Post)) {
```

and if you are using Net 4.8 or older you have to config attribute routing

`````
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);
 
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
 
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
````
`````